# ComboBox does not select binding value initially

Tags: c#, xaml, combobox, uwp, win-universal-app

First of all, not a duplicate.

TextBox and CheckBox work correctly, just not ComboBox.

#### Model

```
internal class Word : _Model
{
    public enum Categories
    {
        Noun,
        Verb,
    }

    private Categories category;
    public Categories Category
    {
        get
        {
            return this.category;
        }
        set
        {
            this.SetProperty(ref this.category,
                             value);
        }
    }
}
```

#### Notify (safe to skip reading this part)

```
internal abstract class _Model : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected bool SetProperty<T>(ref T storage, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (object.Equals(storage, value))
        {
            return false;
        }
        storage = value;
        this.OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
        return true;
    }

    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        var eventHandler = this.PropertyChanged;
        if (eventHandler != null)
        {
            eventHandler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

#### Control (Model)

```
public sealed partial class WordEditor : UserControl
{
    public WordEditor()
    {
        this.Model = new Models.Word();
        this.Model.Category = Models.Word.Categories.Verb;
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    private Models.Word Model { get; set; }

    internal IList<KeyValuePair<Models.Word.Categories, string>> Categories { get { return new List<KeyValuePair<Models.Word.Categories, string>>() { new KeyValuePair<Models.Word.Categories, string>(Models.Word.Categories.Noun, "Noun"), new KeyValuePair<Models.Word.Categories, string>(Models.Word.Categories.Verb, "Verb") }; } }
}
```

#### Binding

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <converters:AnyConverter x:Key="AnyConverter"/>
</UserControl.Resources>

<StackPanel>
    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{x:Bind Path=Categories, Mode=OneTime}"
              DisplayMemberPath="Value"
              SelectedValuePath="Key"
              SelectedValue="{x:Bind Path=Model.Category, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource ResourceKey=AnyConverter}}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

#### Converter

```
internal class AnyConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        return value;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        return value;
    }
}
```

#### Issue

The ComboBox has "Verb" and "Noun" displayed correctly, and selection on "Verb" or "Noun" is reflected by the model correctly.

However, even though Category is set to Verb at the very first place, the ComboBox does not show that.

How to fix it so that the ComboBox selects "Verb" when it first appears?

Comment: Run it in debug and look at the output window. You might have WPF engine throwing some binding exception

Comment: @LuisFilipe No exception.

Comment: Are you getting burned by using `Mode=OneTime`? I feel ComboBoxes like to act stupid when the `SelectedItem` or `SelectedValue` is set prior to the `ItemsSource` being set, but you haven't provided enough evidence to say whether or not that's a relevant issue. We don't have a good picture of how the viewmodel is composed and when the view is bound to it.

Comment: @Guttsy What is more do you need to know? 1) View Model: `x:Bind`, so the control itself; 2) View Model Property: `Model`, or more specific `Model.Category`; 3) Items Source: a list of `KeyValuePair`.

Comment: Since you set `Model.Category` to `1`, so I guess its type is `int`. However in the code above, you declared it as `Categories`. I'm not sure what's the type of your `Model.Category`. In my side, I just declare it as `public int Category { get; set; }` and your code works fine, the ComboBox shows "1" when it first appears. If you can share the whole code or a simple sample that can reproduce your issue would be better.

Comment: @DanteisnotaGeek Truth, I'm a bit new to `x:Bind` and the like. I've got the mindset of a WPF dev :-/

Comment: @JayZuo-MSFT Glad to get some support from the first party. I have edited the question for the minimal viable reproduction. (The `int` thing before the edit is introduced in the question only to simplify the question.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I reproduced your issue. The problem here is `ComboBox.SelectedValue` doesn't work with enumeration type. To test this, we can use a `ComboBox` without binding and set the `SelectedValue` in code-behind like:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cmb" DisplayMemberPath="Value" SelectedValuePath="Key" />

cmb.ItemsSource = Categories;
cmb.SelectedValue = Models.Word.Categories.Verb;
```

Although I've set `Models.Word.Categories.Verb` to `SelectedValue`, but its value still be `null`.
[image]

However, it works when the `Value` type is `int` or `string`. From my WPF experience, enumeration type should also work. I think this may be a bug in UWP.

As a workaround, I think you can use `SelectedIndex` or `SelectedItem` property to select "Verb" when the ComboBox first appears. For example:

In the XAML, use `SelectedIndex` instead of `SelectedValue`:

```
<ComboBox DisplayMemberPath="Value"
          ItemsSource="{x:Bind Path=Categories, Mode=OneTime}"
          SelectedIndex="{x:Bind Path=Model.Category, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource ResourceKey=AnyConverter}}"
          SelectedValuePath="Key" />
```

And change the `Converter` like:

```
internal class AnyConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        return (int)(Models.Word.Categories)value;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        return (Models.Word.Categories)(int)value;
    }
}
```

After this, setting `this.Model.Category = Models.Word.Categories.Verb;` will work.

Comment: `enum` can be discrete in `int`, which is not possible to work with `SelectedIndex`. I guess I have to live with it for now.

Comment: Yeah, `enum` can be discrete in `int`. But by default, the first enumerator has the value 0, and the value of each successive enumerator is increased by 1. If you insist on setting them discrete, you can try using `Array.IndexOf(Enum.GetValues(typeof(Models.Word.Categories)), (Models.Word.Categories)value)` to get the index in `Convert` and `(Models.Word.Categories)Enum.GetValues(typeof(Models.Word.Categories)).GetValue((int)value)` in `ConvertBack`.

Answer (score 0):

At first I thought @Jay Zuo - MSFT was right in that you'd have to convert it to another form (e.g., `int`); however, by using `SelectedItem`, it works! I was using `SelectedValue` like OP, but didn't define `SelectedValuePath` and it wouldn't select the initial value. Binding to `SelectedItem` does even without defining `SelectedValuePath`.

Note, if you bind to `SelectedItem` versus `SelectedIndex`, there's no need whatsoever for a converter.

I tested this with Windows 10 Anniversary Edition (10.0; Build 14393).

**Update**

Turns out I was wrong ;p I ended up rolling out my own converter for more convenience.

```
public abstract class EnumToIntConverter<TEnum> : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        if (value is Enum)
            return (int)value;

        return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        if (value is int)
            return (TEnum)value;

        return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
    }
}

public sealed class MyEnumToIntConverter : EnumToIntConverter<MyEnum>
{
    //Do nothing!
}
```

To clarify, `SelectedIndex` is *absolutely* needed.